# List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen

Tags: python

I have a list (of nested tuples) and I want to eliminate nested tuples which have the same first and last item as their element,
**preserving order**:

```
my_list = [('0.5', '00', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '02', '0-0'),
 ('0.5', '02', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '02', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '03', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '04', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '05', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '06', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '07', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '08', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '09', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '10', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '11', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '13', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '14', '0-0'),
 ('0.5', '15', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '15', '0-0'),
 ('0.5', '15', '0-0')]
```

This is the output I need:

```
[('0.5', '00', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '02', '0-0'),
 ('0.5', '02', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '02', '0-0'),
 ('0.5', '15', '0-0'),
 ('0.75', '15', '0-0'),
 ('0.5', '15', '0-0')]
```

I tried this but didn't worked:

```
from more_itertools import unique_justseen

list(unique_justseen(my_list))
```

Comment: Non of your tuples have same first and list item same? What do you mean?

Comment: @ShivamJha: There are three tuples with the first and last item `'0.5'` and `'0-0'`

Comment: in my example, nested tuples in my_list[3:14] has the same '0.75' and '0-0'

Comment: OP wants the first tuple from each "chunk" where a chunk is defined by having same first and last elements. Seems clear to me. I'd groupby each first and last element run and take the first from the groupby list.

Comment: Your sample output has duplicates: `('0.75', '02', '0-0')` appears twice. What is your question?

Comment: OKAY, that means **the tuples which have the same first and last item as their element** i thought those whose first one equals last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check elements against the previously appended one before appending:

```
out = []
for el in my_list:
    if not out or el[0] != out[-1][0] or el[-1] != out[-1][-1]:
        out.append(el)

print(out)
```

gives

```
[('0.5', '00', '0-0'), ('0.75', '02', '0-0'), ('0.5', '02', '0-0'), ('0.75', '02', '0-0'), ('0.5', '15', '0-0'), ('0.75', '15', '0-0'), ('0.5', '15', '0-0')]
```

Comment: @khaledkoubaa Glad it works. I've answered for the simple case given in the question, which didn't need seem to require anything sophisticated (I'm not worrying too much about the fact that `out[-1]` appears twice here) -- but do also check out ggorlen's answer for a generic approach which you could adapt if you needed to group the items in more complex ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a lambda key which returns the first and last elements of the tuple to group on:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> grouped = [next(g) for _, g in groupby(my_list, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))]
>>> for t in grouped: print(t)
... 
('0.5', '00', '0-0')
('0.75', '02', '0-0')
('0.5', '02', '0-0')
('0.75', '02', '0-0')
('0.5', '15', '0-0')
('0.75', '15', '0-0')
('0.5', '15', '0-0')
```